# Where to add files for Directus 8 front-end hello world?

Tags: directus, headless-cms

Checking out Directus 8 for my first time and there's something simple I'm just not getting and don't see it in the docs. My directory setup is:

```
mydomain.com/public/admin
mydomain.com/public/downloads
mydomain.com/public/extensions
mydomain.com/public/index.php
mydomain.com/public/uploads
```

My expectation is that Directus is in public/admin and I should be able to do what I want to public/index.php for my front-end application. However, when I change that, /admin no longer gives me the login form. I'm just trying to get a hello-world front end going but I don't see how or any documents on how to do it. I'm sure it's something simple I'm just overlooking, but it's turning into one of those things taking me hours to figure out and its driving me crazy...

Basically I have Directus working if I keep the original index.php in my public root, but then how do I set up my front end application if public index.php always redirects to Directus admin?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? Having the same issue here... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I arrived at:

I'm on a shared host, and did notice a comment somewhere about that being an issue. Instead of extracting the public directory contents into my web root, the directory structure is like this:

- `[webroot]/directus/public/admin/`  and
- the directus system directories remain in the `[webroot]/directus/ directory (bin, config, logs, migrations, public, src, vendor);`

From there directus is accessed at mydomain.com/directus/public/admin

Set up this way, I'm able to add my front end in the normal webroot.